# Scientific/Exponential notation with sympy in an ipython notebook 2

Tags: sympy, number-formatting

How can one force scientific notation to any number printed in a ipython notebook using display?

Example:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()

a = Symbol('a')
aval = 1/100
display(Eq(a, aval))
```

produces

=0.01

The desired output is

=1.0 · 10⁻²

or something in that line.

This was partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222681/scientific-exponential-notation-with-sympy-in-an-ipython-notebook) like 6 years ago, but the solution is not applicable to this case

Comment: `ipython` does not control the formatting of individual numbers; it can only manipulate the overall layout.  `aval` is a Python float.  `Eq(a,aval).rhs` is a `sympy.Float`, which is displayed with more trailing 0s.   The display of this `Float` alone, and in an expression like `Eq` is controlled by `sympy` (not Python or ipython).

Comment: See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18477 for some recent changes that might help.

Comment: the changes might help, but one would have to set the options every time a number is displayed? and how with them work with Eq? This is manly the answer in the given post, and I couldn't find a way to make it useful for the situation I have at hand.